# How do I use concatenated string in a DIV?

Tags: javascript, html

I think my concatenating is fine, but my use of it isn't working. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<script>
var str1 = "/images/";
var str2 = "test.jpg";
var res = str1.concat(str2);
</script>

<div class="product-sprite" data-image="res"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

DOM element attributes are not evaluated as variables. You need to assign it to the element property.

```
var res = str1 + str2; // no need to use .concat()
document.querySelector(".product-sprite").dataset.image = res;
```

Comment: Awesome!!! Works great. Thank you... I can stop pounding my head against the wall.